# How does the "specs" BDD framework for Scala work?

Tags: scala, bdd, specs

I'm just getting started with Scala, and I'm wondering which language feature allows you to do this:

```
"PersistentQueue" should {
  "add and remove one item" in {
    withTempFolder {
      val q = new PersistentQueue(folderName, "work", Config.fromMap(Map.empty))
      q.setup

      q.length mustEqual 0
      q.totalItems mustEqual 0
      q.bytes mustEqual 0
      q.journalSize mustEqual 0

      q.add("hello kitty".getBytes)

      q.length mustEqual 1
      q.totalItems mustEqual 1
      q.bytes mustEqual 11
      q.journalSize mustEqual 32

      new String(q.remove.get.data) mustEqual "hello kitty"

      q.length mustEqual 0
      q.totalItems mustEqual 1
      q.bytes mustEqual 0
      q.journalSize mustEqual 33

      q.close
      dumpJournal("work") mustEqual "add(11:0:hello kitty), remove"
    }
  }
}
```

That's from the [unit tests for Kestrel](http://github.com/robey/kestrel/blob/2ae2eabef5ff38073967d21b210ad51349b7428c/src/test/scala/net/lag/kestrel/PersistentQueueSpec.scala).

What's going on here? Does `"PersistentQueue" should` mean that the Scala string class has been extended with a "should" method, or is something else happening here? I had a quick look through the Scala documentation but couldn't see which language features are being used for this code sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like implicit methods being added to the String class to me. [This post](http://scalada.blogspot.com/2008/03/implicit-conversions-magical-and.html) has a demonstration.